# How can I use both OpenGL and Serial port libs in one project?

Tags: java, opengl, serial-port, jogl

I am creating a project that uses these libraries:

```
jogl.jar
gluegen-rt.jar
RXTXcomm.jar
```

I created a Form that shows a drawing using OpenGL and a button that activates the serial communication. When I run the application, the drawing appears, but when I click in the button, the following message appears:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown 
  while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
at SerialOpenGL.SerialComm.getPortIdentifier(SerialComm.java:239)
```

If I edit the file "project.properties" (under the folder "nbproject" in the project source files) removing these lines:

```
run-sys-prop.java.library.path=\
    ${libs.JOGL.classpath}-natives-${natives.platform}${path.separator}\
    ${libs.GLUEGEN-RT.classpath}-natives-${natives.platform}
```

And if I remove, in the main class, all calls to jogl library, no error appear and the serial communication runs very well.

So, my question is: 
How can I add the path of RXTXcomm.jar to java.library.path?
It could be an error in the instalation of the RXTXcomm.jar?

Comment: You should use JOGL 2, it doesn't require to modify the Java library path, it supports automated native library extraction and loading from JARs, just put jogamp-far.jar into your classpath and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, in the next time I will be more specific. Anyway, I have solved the problem here, the instalation of library RXTXcomm.jar was wrong.    I added the line <br/>`C:\\Windows\\system32${path.separator}`  <br/>  bellow `run-sys-prop.java.library.path=\`  <br/> in the file <br/>`project.properties`  <br/>      and the application works.

Comment: You still use JOGL 1 which is obsolete and unmaintained unlike JOGL 2.